# Audacious can't play some m4a files, but vlc can play it

Tags: sound, vlc, audacious, m4a

I have some audio files with m4a format. But some of the file can't be played with Audacious but can be played with VLC. Why did it happen?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been mentioned in a bug report on the Audacious bug tracker:

[Certain .m4a files do not play](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/425)

To play these files in Audacious you will need to have use `ffaudio`: make sure your copy of Audacious is using the 'FFmpeg Plugin'.

See the image below which demonstrates the FFmpeg Plugin *selected* in the Audacious Settings:

[image]

And then all should be well...